# c#: nameof is returning temporary variable inside a loop

Tags: c#

nameof is returning the temporary variable inside a loop.
any idea how to resolve this scenario.
The desired result should be the original name of the variables.

thanks.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/s9ctPF

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string var1 ="asdasd1";
        string var2 ="asdasd2";
        //this is desired result
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(var1));

        object[] variableList =
        {
            var1,var2
        };
        
        List<Variable> objectList = new List<Variable>();
        
        foreach (var i in variableList)
        {
                objectList.Add(new Variable { VariableName = nameof(i), VariableValue = (string)i });
                //requirement: dont want i, desired result to be var1 : asdasd1...
                Console.WriteLine(nameof(i) +" : "+  i);
        }

    }
    
    public class Variable
    {
        public string VariableName { get; set; }
        public string VariableValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your source code to your question. Then describe what you are getting as output (paste the output into the question as code). Then describe what you were expecting, and why. The `nameof` operator takes a name (a variable name, a method name, etc) - at compile time - and converts it to a const string for compilation purpose. Example `nameof(i)` will be compiles _as if_ it was `"i"`.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour, what were you expecting?

Comment: hi i have put the desired result in the comment c# code, sorry.

Comment: [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) cannot work like that.

Comment: The advantage of `nameof` is best seen during refactoring. If you have `nameof(ComplicatedClass)` (which gets translated to `"ComplicatedClass"`), and you rename the class to `Simple`, that string will get refactored to `"Simple"`. It also promotes good spelling

Comment: The other thing to know is that objects don't have a _name_. If you write `var Bob = new SomeClass();` and then `var Bill = Bob;`, the object is named neither Bob nor Bill. Variables have names, objects don't - and object know nothing of the Variables that refer to them (if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected result, `nameof()` is a special syntax only function that will return the name of the variable that you pass in to the function.

so `nameof(Myconvoluted.namespace.instance.Q)` will *always* return `"Q"`.
It doesn't evaluate or even look at the target of the expression, it is operating on the expression itself.

If you need a reference to the original name of the variable, then you will need to pass that through to the context in a way that it can be resolved, in this case, why not just instantiate the `variableList` up front:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string var1 ="asdasd1";
    string var2 ="asdasd2";
    //this is desired result
    Console.WriteLine(nameof(var1));

    List<Variable> variableList =
    {
        new Variable { VariableName = nameof(var1), VariableValue = var1 },
        new Variable { VariableName = nameof(var2), VariableValue = var2 },
    };
    
    foreach (var i in variableList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.VariableName +" : "+ i.VariableValue);
    }

}

public class Variable
{
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
    public string VariableValue { get; set; }
}
```

if this is too verbose, then put some helpers in there:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string var1 ="asdasd1";
    string var2 ="asdasd2";

    List<Variable> variableList =
    {
        new Variable(nameof(var1), var1),
        new Variable(nameof(var2), var2),
    };
    
    foreach (var i in variableList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i.Name}: {i.Value}");
    }

}

public class Variable
{
    public Variable(string name, object value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An example of real-world scenarios that work like this is in reflection code with `PropertyInfo`, `MethodInfo` or when building `SqlParameter` objects. If the name of the variable is important, then you should deliberately pass it through.

Comment: hi Chris, the reason I declare an array is because there are tons of variable, so it should be cleaner, any method to loop through the array but not deliberately pass it through. (adding array element to the object list)

Comment: Adding _magic_ code to resolve information at run time doesn't make things clean at all, it makes the code harder to interpret and harder to debug. Perhaps post a snippet of your real code as a new question and we can help to identify a simple solution, your current code doesn't demonstrate how this solution is any less verbose. a big question is why do you need the values in this generic structure at all, if this is a logging only requirement, then there are different solutions to that.

Comment: thanks for your advice, Chris, appreciate your answers.

Comment: The biggest hole in trying to identify the name of a variable at all, is what to do when there is no name? For instance, what should be the name of an inline static string `"like this"` or what if the variable was defined in one method, and passed through to X number of other methods. TBH the only times I've come across this requirement was early on before I really understood the actual problem that I was trying to achieve. Its an indication that you are trying to do something the wrong way. Look me up through my profile if you want to chat more about this.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered `nameof` will literally just give you the name of the variable you are passing it. This isn't too surprising since `nameof` is just an expression which is evaluated at compile time.

If the goal is just for a name to travel with the value then you could try a structure that would hold both - be it a class you build or a tuple.